# Dialog in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, android-compose-dialog

I am new in Jetpack Compose. I just implemented an `AlertDialog` in Jetpack Compose. I'am not clear about Dialog show and dismiss process. Here is sample code:

```
@Composable
fun CreateAlertDialog() {
    Column {
        val openDialog = remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

        Button(
            onClick = {
                openDialog.value = true
            },
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(16.dp)
                .fillMaxWidth()
        ) {
            Text(text = "Open Dialog")
        }

        if (openDialog.value){
            AlertDialog(
                onDismissRequest = {
                    openDialog.value = false
                },
                title = {
                    Text(text = "Dialog Title")
                },
                text = {
                    Text(text = "Text content")
                },
                confirmButton = {
                    Button(
                        onClick = {
                            openDialog.value = false
                        }
                    ) {
                        Text(text = "Ok")
                    }
                },
                dismissButton = {
                    Button(
                        onClick = {
                            openDialog.value = false
                        }
                    ) {
                        Text(text = "Cancel")
                    }
                },
                modifier = Modifier.padding(start = 32.dp, end = 32.dp)
            )
        }
    }
}
```

This works fine, but i am not clear how dialog is dismissed here. Dialog is showing based on `MutableState`

It shows dialog when `openDialog.value` this is true.
What happen after a `Button` click ? When a `Button` is clicked `openDialog.value` becomes `false` and `dialog` is dismissed.

**Where is dialog dismiss code executed?**

**How this state is handled ?**

Can any one can explain this would be helpful to me.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Where is dialog dismiss code executed?**
--> As soon as you click the button and the value of `openDialog` is changed. Recomposition will triggered for your Composable function and UI will be redrawn and accordingly your dialog visibility will be changed.
So when the value of `openDialog` is false the dialog code will be skipped.
Please check this -> https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/mental-model#recomposition

**How this state is handled ?**
--> State is usually handled with `remember` and `mutableState`.
`remember` allows you to keep the value  of the object in memory incase of the recomposition.
and `mutableState` stores the value and can trigger recomposition when value is changed.

Taking your function as an example.
Button clicked and value of `openDialog` is true. This will cause recomposition. Now, when `CreateAlertDialog()` is again invoke by recomposition the value of `openDialog` will remain true as it is wrapped in `remember{}`. Now the dialog will be visible.